# Prolog predicate that returns the numbers of moves required to solve towers of hanoi

Tags: prolog, towers-of-hanoi

```
moves(N,R) :-
N = 0, R is 0. 
moves(N,R) :-
N = 1, R is 1. 
moves(N,R) :-    
N > 1, T1 is N - 1, T2 is N-1, moves(T1,R1), moves(T2,R2), R is R1 + R2 + 1.
```

I am getting uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,moves/1),top_level/0) 
when i attempt to run this query and hints will be helpful thanks!

moves(7). returns the error above

Comment: In case you are using a prolog shell (CLI) try `retractall(move(_,_,_)).`

Comment: What are you typing in to call this? Your error message says you called `move` with one argument, but such a predicate doesn't exist.

Comment: im using move(7). to call after i use the gprolog command and [lab04] to compile.!

Comment: so i need more i thought the second parameter was R to store the value returned. but i could be wrong

Comment: @lurker 
 
im using move(7). to call after i use the gprolog command and [lab04] to compile.!

Comment: You don't have a predicate or fact `moves` with one argument. So you have an error. Why are you calling `moves(7)` or `move(7)`? All of your `moves` predicates require two arguments, and your code doesn't show any such predicate called `move`. Perhaps there's more in `lab04` you haven't shown.

Comment: ok i figured it out @vmg moves(7,X) was correct i didnt know how to call the function Thanks guys sorry for being such a NOOB!

Comment: Also, for the sake of clarity, consider replacing your first clause with `moves(0, 0)` and your second with `moves(1, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
moves(0,0). 
moves(1,1). 
moves(N,R) :-    
N > 1, T1 is N-1, moves(T1,R1), moves(T1,R2), R is R1 + R2 + 1.
```